# recursively copying data from s3 changing the folder structure using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a data in s3 sr=ab/pt=01/pt=02/pt=03 which multiple folders. underneath pt=03 contains all the data.

```
`
old_bucket_name = 'bucket'
old_prefix = 'sr=ab/pt=01/pt=02/pt=03'
new_bucket_name = 'bucket'
new_prefix = old_prefix.split("=")[3].strip()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name )
new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name )
for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
  old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                 Key': obj.key}
  new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix)
  new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
  new_obj.copy(old_source)`
```

I am getting following output

```
03/list of files
```

I am expecting something like the following

```
ab/01/02/03    
ab/01/03/00    
ab/01/03/01    
ab/01/03/02
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you want to reformat the prefix from

`sr=ab/pt=01/pt=02/pt=03` to `ab/01/02/03`

And it seems you simply copy somebody code without knowing the python function.

I Assume the front part of the `=` sign are random, I will not take shortcut retaining the "/" separator. So multiple split join required.

```
old_prefix = 'sr=ab/pt=01/pt=02/pt=03'
step1 = old_prefix.split('/') 
step2 = [x.split('=')[1] for x in step1]
new_prefix = "/".join(step2)
```

You can make above code leaner.

```
new_prefix = "/".join([x.split('=')[1] for x in old_prefix.split('/')])
```

Comment: I am still getting IndexError: list index out of range on step 2 and if i use only last line new_prefix- same error. Sorry i am new to python

Comment: For newbie, it is recommended to use Jupyter Notebooks to learn each value spit out.  Because it can be caused by failure to indent  (correct indent is important in python).  If you don't know how to use logging, try to use "print" to diagnose the output value before performing the copy.